# retrieve data stored in the WordPress db by Visual Form Builder

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the plugin [Visual Form Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/) (not pro) for WordPress. I've created a form, and all the data submitted are correctly sent by email. These data are automatically stored in the WordPress database, but I don't know how to retrieve them.

For example, if I want to show a page with the result of a query to those data, how can I do that? I enabled the execution of PHP code inside the page, so I can query the db using PHP. However I don't know the name of the db, the tables neither the fields of the database. 
What's the solution?

Thank you

Comment: This answers your question, I think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292760/visual-form-builder-pro-vfb-pro-which-table-are-the-form-entries-stored-in