# Visual Form Builder Pro (VFB Pro): Which table are the form entries stored in?

Tags: wordpress

I can't find my test form submissions anywhere!

Any idea which table the submitted form information is stored in?

VFB Pro Version 3.2.2
WordPress

Answer (score 1):

Executing the SQL statement below:

```
select * from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_vfb_form_id'
```

Will get you all the data from all vfb forms.

To get data from specific forms:

You have to find your form id (found in the wp_vfbp_forms table)

Let's say it is form number 5 - in order to get all entries found in form number 5 you'd select as follows:

```
select * from wp_postmeta where post_id in (select post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_vfb_form_id' and meta_value = '5')
```

That'll give you a table  that looks like this:

```
Meta_id post_id  meta_key       meta_value

6954    4138    _vfb_form_id    5
6955    4138    _vfb_seq_num    1
6956    4138    _vfb_entry_id   4138
6957    4138    vfbp-spam   
6958    4138    _vfb_field-52   somebody@somewhere.com
6959    4138    _vfb_field-53   08/01/2018
6960    4138    _vfb_field-56   08/24/2018
6961    4138    _vfb_field-54   France
7052    4168    _vfb_form_id    5
7053    4168    _vfb_seq_num    1
7054    4168    _vfb_entry_id   4168
7055    4168    vfbp-spam   
7056    4168    _vfb_field-52   somebodyelse@somewhere.com
7057    4168    _vfb_field-53   08/18/2018
7058    4168    _vfb_field-56   07/25/2018
7059    4168    _vfb_field-54   England, Ireland
7060    4168    _vfb_field-65   Yes
7061    4168    _vfb_field-61   +1 555-555-5555
7062    4168    _vfb_field-66   No
7063    4168    _vfb_field-67   
7064    4168    _vfb_field-68   Thank you
7270    4168    _edit_lock  1531934142:113
7271    4168    _edit_last  113
7272    4168    _expiration-date-status saved
7273    4168    _vfb_field-58
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the table is called wp_postmeta.  Unfortunately, the data are not stored in a convenient format.  I'm just working on this problem now, so stay tuned.